# I keep getting NoSuchElementException while trying to access. What can I do?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

So I'm trying to get into web scraping and web automation. I have just started with selenium so I'm a little bit lost on what to do. I have looked here for similar questions and so far none have worked so can the problem be?

Here's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver                    
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys    
 


url = 'https://starcitygames.com/search/?search_query=Lantern%20of%20insight'

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)
browser.maximize_window()
browser.implicitly_wait(20)

prices = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('div.hawk-results-item__options-table-cell hawk-results-item__options-table-cell--price childAttributes')
browser.switch_to.frame(prices)

for each in prices:
    p = each.text
    print(p)
```

And I get the following Error message:

```
 raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"div.hawk-results-item__options-table-cell hawk-results-item__options-table-cell--price childAttributes"}
```

IF it helps the html of the element I'm trying to access is the following:

```
<div class="hawk-results-item__options-table-cell hawk-results-item__options-table-cell--price childAttributes">.99</div>
```

So what can I change? I already switch from find_element_by_class to a css selector.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: can you provide the html of the element you're trying to access?

Comment: `<div class="hawk-results-item__options-table-cell hawk-results-item__options-table-cell--price childAttributes">$3.99</div>`  That's how it shows at the google dev tools section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with your approach.
First of all, the find_element_by_* functions are deprecated so you should use the find_element() functions instead. You'll need this import to do that.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Considering you are trying to loop through the found elements i suppose you meant to use find_elements() which returns a list of elements that match the given locator.
When using cssSelector, you need to specify the html tag then open [] brackets and specify the attribute.

In your case this should work

```
prices = browser.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class='hawk-results-item__options-table-cell hawk-results-item__options-table-cell--price childAttributes']")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solved the issue. By the way are there any good books or resources I can use to practice with selenium?

Comment: No problem, glad i could help. As far as resources go, i mainly use the official selenium docs and just practicing a lot. For xpaths i used this cheatsheet (https://devhints.io/xpath) a lot when i started out, very helpful imo.

Comment: Again thanks a lot! I'll keep practicing and I'll check the docs down the road.